# boost threadpool using boost::asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to create boost threadpool using boost asio with a work queue. But I am stuck at one point, I need a monitoring function which should keep running and keep track of queue. I am not sure how I can write that, currently I put it in my thread pool class. I am also trying to write seprate thread with global function. Can someone suggest any way?

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

class threadWork
{
public:
virtual void run()=0;
};

class thread_pool 
{ 
private: 
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_; 
  boost::asio::io_service::work work_; 
  boost::thread_group threads_; 
  std::size_t available_; 
  boost::mutex mutex_;

  list<shared_ptr<threadWork>> workQueue;

public: 


  thread_pool( std::size_t pool_size ) : work_( io_service_ ), available_( pool_size ) 
  { 
    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < pool_size; ++i ) 
    { 
      threads_.create_thread( boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_ ) ); 
    } 
  } 


  ~thread_pool() 
  { 

    io_service_.stop(); 

try 
    { 
      threads_.join_all(); 
    } 
    catch ( ... ) {} 
  } 

  void enqueue(shared_ptr<threadWork> work)
  {
  workQueue.push_back(work);
  }

  void keepRunning() // how to call this ?
  {
  while(true)
  {
      boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock( mutex_ ); 

      if ( 0 == available_ ) // If no threads are available, then sleep. 
      {
          boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
      }
      else
      {

          if(workQueue.empty() != true)
          {
               --available_;  
               io_service_.post( boost::bin(&thread_pool::wrap_task,this , workQueue));
               workQueue.pop_front();
          }
      }
  }
  }

 private: 

  void wrap_task(list<shared_ptr<threadWork>>& workQueue ) 
  { 
    try 
    { 
    workQueue.front()->run(); // Run the user supplied task. 
    } 

catch ( ... )  // Suppress all exceptions. 
{

} 

boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock( mutex_ );  
    ++available_; 
  } 
}; 

class someWork:public threadWork
{
public:
virtual void run()
{
    cout<<"some long task \n";
     boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
}
};

int main()
{

thread_pool pool(10);

pool.keepRunning(); // this stuck code so where to start this ?

shared_ptr<threadWork> w(new someWork);

pool.enqueue(w);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think boost already has threadpool http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks , i am considuring using threadpool from threadpool.sourceforge.net

Comment: this example code does not compile, there are several errors, an example `io_service_.post( boost::bin(&thread_pool::wrap_task,this , workQueue));` should be `boost::bind`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes an ASIO Threadpool....

Comment: this example code does not compile , ssorry for that i will check and update soon. as of now i am using think-async.com/Asio/Recipes link by mark , it works up to some extend. thanks to all of you.

Comment: threadpool has the problem that it doesn't queue at all - if all threads are busy adding a task fails. So to be useful you need to add a (threadsafe) queue to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boost::asio::deadline_timer` to periodically have your `io_service` update an atomic variable representing the queue length. A class member function could return the queue length on demand (by value).